# how can I find text in xmlns with elementtree

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I have this xml:

```
<office:body>
<office:text>
<text:sequence-decls>
<text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>
<text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/>
<text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Text"/>
<text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Drawing"/>
</text:sequence-decls>
<text:p text:style-name="Standard">
<office:annotation>...</office:annotation>
foobar
</text:p>
</office:text>
</office:body>
```

I want to find the text "foobar" with elementtree since instead of "foobar" can be any text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the XML document looks like this (with declared namespaces):

```
<office:document-content xmlns:office="http://openoffice.org/2000/office"
                         xmlns:text="http://openoffice.org/2000/text">

  <office:body>
    <office:text>
      <text:sequence-decls>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Text"/>
        <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Drawing"/>
      </text:sequence-decls>
      <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
        <office:annotation>...</office:annotation>
        foobar
      </text:p>
    </office:text>
  </office:body>

</office:document-content>
```

You can then get the "foobar" string using this program:

```python
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse("foobar.xml")
ann = root.find(".//{http://openoffice.org/2000/office}annotation")
print ann.tail.strip()
```

Here, the [`ElementTree.find()`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.find) method is used to find the `office:annotation` element and the [`Element.tail`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) attribute returns the text content after the element's end-tag.